# how can i use java to output an R graph

Tags: java, r

I have a java program that produces a String[][], this array is then turned into a csv file.
For example my program may output in something like this,

```
String[][] test = {{name, bc1, bc2, bc3},{name1, 10,20,30},
                   {name2, 5,15,20},{name3, 6,12,18}}
```

and the csv (test.csv) file looks like

```
name   bc1   bc2   bc3
name1  10    20    30
name2  5     15    20
name3  6     12    18
```

Now I could take this csv file and create a R graph, for instance

```
testR -> read.csv("test.csv")
boxplot(testR)
```

My question is: Can I run R "within" java and have my java program handle R and perhaps output the R graph as a pdf or another graphical file?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [JRI/rJava](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/) project which provides a Java/R interface. After you download the package, see the examples directory.

Another option is to use the [RCaller](http://www.mhsatman.com/rcaller.php) library (though I've never tried it myself...this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435619/calling-r-from-java-faster-alternative-to-rcaller) suggests potential performance issues).